# Modeling/sculpting foot

Tags: modeling, sculpting

This is a cry for help lol
I'm a beginner in blender and right now I'm stuck in this foot modeling. I've brrn trying to reshape it but I just can't get a nice result...
Can someone shed a light on what I could do to keep this going?
Much thanks!!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

- Select the edges and bevel:

[image]

[image]

- Enable the *Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins* option, select the front faces and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*, in the Operator box enable the *Offset Even* option:

[image]

[image]

- Enable the *Proportional Editing* option/*Connected Only* and give some corrections in *Edit* mode:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! it worked :)